# Python multiple intersection

Tags: python, set, intersection

I reimplemented the set in python but i have some problem with multiple intersection.... I followed the book Learning Python but i have problem with my code

```
class Set:
    def __init__(self,value=[]):
        self.data = []
        self.remDupli(value)

    def remDupli(self,val):
        for i in val:
            if i not in self.data:
                self.data.append(i)

    def intersect(self,other):
        val=[]
        for i in self.data:
            for k in other:
                if i == k:
                    val.append(i)
        return Set(val)

    def union(self,other):
        val=self.data
        for i in other:
            if i not in self.data:
                val.append(i)
        return Set(val)

    def __or__(self,a):       return self.union(a)
    def __and__(self,a):      return self.intersect(a)
    def __len__(self):        return len(self.data)
    def __getitem__(self,key):  return self.data[key]
    def __repr__(self):       return 'Set: ' +repr(self.data)

class Extend(Set):
    def intersect(self, *others):
        val = []
        for i in self:
            for x in others:
                if i in x:
                    val.append(i)
        return Set(val)
```

but when I run this:

```
x = Extend([1,2,3,4])
y = Extend([3,4,5])
z = Extend([0,1,2])
print(x & y & z)
print(x.intersect(y, z))
```

I have two different behavior

```
Set: []
Set: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I don't understand because the second is different, in my opinion they should have the same behavior, anyone can help me?

Comment: `x.intersect(y.intersect(z))` will have the same behaviour as `x & y & z`

Answer (score 6):

`Extend.intersect` does not calculate intersection between many sets. It calculates intersection between `self` and *union* of `others`.

The results are different because `x & y & z` calls `Extend.intersect(Extend.intersect(x,y), z)`, while `x.intersect(y,z)` calls `Extend.intersect(x, *[y,z])` and given what `Extend.intersect` *actually* does, those happen to be different operations.

Comment: Can I change my code in order to have the same behavior? or do I have only to change way to call in this way x.intersect(y.intersect(z))?

Comment: @fege Depends, but I feel that your real problem is that you got the algorithm wrong, so you have to fix it, not the calling code.

Comment: `if all(i in x for x in others): val.append(i)`

Comment: I think the Extend.intersect should use the base implementation defined in the Set class. BTW, I would expect Extend.intersect to return an Extend object.